# Is it possible to restrict the amount of data ('gate' the data) sent to unauthenticated (angularFire) clients in firebase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Here I am fetching the data using angularFire:

```
angular.module('FireApp', ['firebase'])
  .controller('Document', function($scope, $routeParams, angularFire){
    var url = "https://my-account.firebaseio.com/test" + "/" + $routeParams.data;
    angularFire(url, $scope, data);
});
```

The problem is that this will load the 'https://my-account.firebaseio.com/test/data' and all of its children and grandchildren etc..
The '/data' is an array of objects, which can (but doesn't have to - it could very well be an array of Strings) look similar to the parent of "/data":

```
data: ["0" : {
    "data" : [...],
    "meta" : {
      "active" : false
    },
    "sign" : [...]
  },
  "1" : {
    "data" : [...],
    "meta" : {
      "active" : true
    },
    "sign" : {...}
  },
  "2" : {
    "data" : [...],
    "meta" : {
      "active" : false
    },
    "sign" : {...}
  }]
```

Basically, I want all unauthenticated angularFire clients to receive ONLY those elements of the data array, where the boolean flag meta.active = true, i.e. the active flag need to decide whereas its grandparent will be sent to the client upon the angularFire request. Also unauthenticated clients can't write/edit any of the data. The rule I want to set should say: "whenever the 'active = false' flag is set do not send the flag's grandparent to the angularFire client, unless the client is authenticated.". So yes the rule need to be relative rather than absolute.
Only authenticated clients should be able to receive/edit all the data.
Can I make such rules with Firebase Simple Login and Security Rules? 
If this can't be done for a grandparent, the 'active' flag can be moved one level up to affect its parent instead.
Thank you for your time,
Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to restructure your data in order to achieve this with Firebase. See this blog post for some background on this: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

One way to structure the data would be to create two separate lists, one for active items and another for inactive items. When an item becomes active or inactive, be sure to remove it from one list and put it in another.

```js
{
  "active": {
    0: {
      "data": {...},
      "sign": {...}
    }
  },
  "inactive": {
    0: {
      "data": {...},
      "sign": {...}
    }
  }
}
```

In your security rules, you can simply prevent access to inactive items to unauthenticated users:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "active": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "inactive": {
      ".read": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Anant. Your solution looks sound, but will this work an arbitrary number of nested 'data' nodes that also contain active/inactive separation?

Comment: I'd appreciate your prompt answer to the above, since I'd like to move my project forward.

Comment: No, it won't work for nested nodes. If you want to nest, I'd consider creating a global active/inactive list (using FirebaseRef.push() to generate unique IDs for each object), and then store the names of these objects as references inside the data nodes. You can then nest, but you'll also need to fetch the actual object after retrieving its name from the appropriate list.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out what you meant and that's what I'll do. Now it seems the best solution for me. Cheers